# How to use `adb push` after mounting /system R/W without losing R/W permissions to install app as /system/apps?

Tags: applications, adb, root-access, installation, system-apps

I'm using a rooted Revvl 6 5G - TMAF025G_0.05.29 - MT6833 - Android 12. Without a `recovery.img`, I rooted using `Magisk_Patched-boot_a.img`. After this, I used the RO2RW module to aid in making the partitions R/W mountable with:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

The goal is to install apps as system apps using:

```
adb push xplore.apk /system/apps
```

How do I go from mounting the `/system` partition as R/W to 'adb push' without losing the permissions? How do I push `xplore.apk` to `/system/apps` while the partition is still mounted R/W? If I exit the root command and then exit the Android shell, the partition resets to normal. So I'm trying to figure out how to transition.

Answer (score 2):

`adb push` is never affected from calling `su` from within a shell.
If you execute `su` within a shell a new shell instance is created that get the root permissions.

However `adb push` does not use a shell at all. Instead the push operation is directly executed by the `adbd` on the Android device.

The only way to get root permissions in `adb push` is by calling `adb root`. If the `adbd` running on the device supports it, `adbd` will restart itself and keep the root permissions.

If you now execute `adb push` all operations will be executed with root permissions.

Comment: So the response I am getting from pushing: `C:\Platform-Tools>adb push Magisk.v26.3.apk /system/apps adb: error: failed to copy 'Magisk.v26.3.apk' to '/system/apps': remote couldn't create file: Permission denied Magisk.v26.3.apk: 0 files pushed. 55.0 MB/s (982920 bytes in 0.017s)` comes after I use `adb root` and after `adb shell`, `su`, `mount -o remount,rw /system`, and `exit` twice to back out to `adb push`.. How can I achieve the proper permissions to push to the root directory?

Comment: I tried running `su`, `mount -o remount,rw /system` from the smartphone shell and then tried adb push from the PC and got the response:

`C:\Platform-Tools>adb push Magisk.v26.3.apk /system/apps
adb F 09-12 22:25:50 11244  2512 file_sync_client.cpp:326] protocol fault: failed to read stat response: No error`

Comment: @NinjaAdmin If you can not directly adb push you first have to push the file to a place where you can write (e.g. `/sdcard`), then open an adb shell, execute su and finally copy the file from /sdcard/ to /system/apps.